# Is there a way to find the next key in a map, given a (non-begin()) starting key?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` that is being used to implement a symbol table for an interpreted language. This is replacing an older implementation that just used packed strings. The language allows a programmer to query for the next symbol name given an arbitrary name which may or may not actually exist. If I had a symbol table where ALLISON and COREY where defined, someone might ask "What's the first symbol that comes after BUTCH?"

Is there a way to "seed" an iterator with an initial value that may not be in the map? Or am I stuck always enumerating from `begin()` and comparing until the returned name is greater than the one passed in?

Alternatively, is there a better data structure that does provide this type of functionality?

Comment: [`std::map::upper_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)?

Comment: If you are enumerating a map, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: "someone might ask "What's the first symbol that comes after BUTCH" This is actually a rather unlikely question. A more plausible one would be "ELISON is not in the map, what could it be a misspelling of?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several data structures that can be used to accomplish this task. I would guess that the most efficient is a `trie` of some sort. However, since you are working with a symbol table that probably has a small number of entries, the standard solution suggested by @tastewar is probably the most appropriate. The following code illustrates how to use `std::upper_bound` in this scenario.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using Map = std::map<std::string,std::string>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Map symbols = { { "alignas", "ALIGNAS" },
                    { "alignof", "ALIGNOF" },
                    { "and", "AND" },
                    { "and_eq", "AND_EQ" },
                    { "asm", "ASM" },
                    { "atomic_cancel", "ATOMIC_CANCEL" }
    };

    // auto iter = std::upper_bound(symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), "amex",
    //                             [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    //                                 return a < b.first;
    //                             });

    // This is simpler.
    auto iter = symbols.upper_bound("amex");

    std::cout << iter->first << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
and
```

Comment: The big-O of this isn’t as good as @Yksisarvinen’s suggestion of `std::map::upper_bound`.

Comment: @Ben I updated the code. The `std::map` member is simpler to use and more efficient.